# How do I use an image as term reference in Drupal 7 and Commerce Kickstart?

Tags: commerce, taxonomy-terms

I want to display a list of fruits in flavours taxonomy. I can easily display the term as term reference but I want an image (specifically the taxonomy image) as the list and clicking the image of the taxonomy the main image of the product should change, i.e. when clicked in strawberry it should show up strawberry cake.

Its term reference is working perfectly fine but I just want the images in place of text.
I have done with color and it works fine.  In other words I need a solution for how to display taxonomy image in the same way as they display color in [Commerce Kickstart](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).

Comment: You might need to expand the question to get an effective answer.

Comment: @Obliquely I am asking if it is possible to display taxonomy image as how they display color in commerce kickstart?Did you get me?

Comment: After searching for days I finally found the solution.First Follow the steps mentioned in the Commerce Fancy Attribute Module and instead of adding a text field add an image field for Vocabulary and add the image you want to display.(put the image small icon size so that the display wont be distorted).And on product variation add a term reference. The main part is in the manage display in Vocabulary we have to choose the format as Image and on Vocabulary we should check  Enable this field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms and choose type as Rendered Item.U are done.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/59954598/myimage.png See the image for reference.

Answer (score 2):

[Acknowledgement: The solution given in comments to self by Saurav works.  Since Saurav hasn't been seen in nearly a year, and comments are ephemeral at SE, I've taken the liberty of expanding the solution suggested in these comments into a full answer, so that the question and answer shall not be deleted as "abandoned" as defined on SE.]

First, install and enable the [**Commerce Fancy Attributes**](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_fancy_attributes) module.

Then, follow the steps suggested under "Example usage" on the [**Commerce Fancy Attributes**](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_fancy_attributes) project page, but instead of adding a text field, add an image field for Vocabulary and add the image you want to display:

1. Create an Image vocabulary. Add an image field that shall hold the images you want to use.
2. Go to the "Manage Display" screen of that vocabulary, click the tab called "Add to Cart form - Attribute", enable only the Image field (with the label hidden).
3. Create several terms with images associated. Use the image small icon size so that the display wont be distorted.
4. Add an Image `taxonomy_term_reference` field to a product type.
5. When you add the Image field on the product type, tick the checkbox "Enable this field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms". For the "Attribute selection widget", and choose the type "Rendered term".

Example:

[image]